# Get useState to update immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to change a value in a state hook depending where the user clicks. My issue is that every time I call an `onClick` method, the state is updating with the previous value. 
I've seen that useState is asynchronous and I need to use useEffect in order to get the correct values, but I have no idea how to do it. Any help ?

Here is my simplified code :

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    content: "",
    rating: ""
});

const { content, rating } = formData;

const onChangeAgree = async e => {
  setFormData({ ...formData, rating: "agree"});
}

const onChangeDisagree = async e  => {
  setFormData({ ...formData, rating: "disagree"});
}

...


<div onClick={e => onChangeAgree(e)}>Agree</div>
<div onClick={e => onChangeDisagree(e)}>Disagree</div>
```

Comment: Try removing `async` from the handlers. Provide a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Also, if you are not using handler methods for anything else than updating the state, you could call `setFormData` directly